# object has no attribute 'index'

Tags: python, dataframe, pandasql

```
import pandas as pd
from pandasql import sqldf

class ABC:
    def __init__(self):
        self.details = {'Name' : ['Ankit', 'Aishwarya', 'Shaurya', 'Shivangi'],'Age' : [23, 21, 22, 21]}
    self.df = pd.DataFrame(self.details)

objAbc=ABC()  

for i,rowObject in sqldf("select distinct Name from objAbc.df").iterrows(): 
    print(rowObject.Name)
```

---

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-21-aaba2874542d> in <module>
      8 objAbc=ABC()
      9 
---> 10 for i,rowObject in sqldf("select distinct Name from objAbc.df").iterrows():
     11     print(rowObject.Name)
     12 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandasql\sqldf.py in sqldf(query, env, db_uri)
    154     >>> sqldf("select avg(x) from df;", locals())
    155     """
--> 156     return PandaSQL(db_uri)(query, env)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandasql\sqldf.py in __call__(self, query, env)
     56                     continue
     57                 self.loaded_tables.add(table_name)
---> 58                 write_table(env[table_name], table_name, conn)
     59 
     60             try:

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandasql\sqldf.py in write_table(df, tablename, conn)
    119                        message='The provided table name \'%s\' is not found exactly as such in the database' % tablename)
    120         to_sql(df, name=tablename, con=conn,
--> 121                index=not any(name is None for name in df.index.names))  # load index into db if all levels are named
    122 
    123 

AttributeError: 'ABC' object has no attribute 'index'
```

**
I want to iterate through dataframe defined in class ABC using pandasql. sqldf function but Getting Error.

'ABC' object has no attribute 'index'

PS: As per requirement it's mandatory to use sqldf of pandasql.

Please Help
**

Comment: Did you try to put the self.df obit inside the __init__ method ?

Comment: I think that pandasql can not find df in objABC.df. You could try to add a method name sqlquery to your ABC class which could execute the query using instance df property (writing df not self.df)

Comment: Tried but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I found is subclassing data frame :

```
import() pandas as pd
from pandasql import sqldf

class ABC(pd.DataFrame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        details = {'Name' : ['Ankit', 'Aishwarya', 'Shaurya', 'Shivangi'],'Age' : [23, 21, 22, 21]}
  
        super().__init__(details, *args, **kwargs)

        #self._details = details
        object.__setattr__(self, "details", details )

objAbc = ABC()
for index,row in sqldf("select Name from objAbc").iterrows():
    print(row.Name)
```

Seems that pandasql can’t find class variables. Note that details can not be set self.details due to warning that you can not add column.